# Yet another curious convolution

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Some time ago, I found the following algorithmic problema:

> Count the number of distinct unrooted, unordered, labeled trees of $n$ nodes where each node has at most $k$ neighbors.

Given that the formula for the number of such trees with $n\ge2$ nodes having a degree sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots a_n$ is
$$\frac{(n-2)!}{\prod(a_i-1)!}$$
It is easy to see that the requested number is given by the coefficient of $x^{2n-2}$ in
$$(n-2)!\times \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{x^i}{(i-1)!}\right)^{n}$$
**Question:** Is there a closed form to count the number of trees with such constraints?